# Rails router doesn't see method post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in routes.rb i have line:

```
resources :comments
```

but when i come to /comments/create i see:

```
No route matches [POST] "/comments/create"
```

...

```
comments_path       GET     /comments(.:format)             comments#index
                    POST    /comments(.:format)             comments#create
new_comment_path    GET     /comments/new(.:format)         comments#new
edit_comment_path   GET     /comments/:id/edit(.:format)    comments#edit
comment_path        GET     /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#show
                    PATCH   /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update
                    PUT     /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#update
                    DELETE  /comments/:id(.:format)         comments#destroy
```

What is wrong? Class and action are exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at line 2 in your `rake routes` output. 
You should POST to `/comments` in order to fire `create` action.